# Custom Domain for SFMC Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, custom-domain

All of our SFMC Landing Pages have a URL akin to:

http://pages.mail.domain.com/keyword/

Is it possible to configure something like:

http://www.otherdomain.com/keyword

If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be the same domain as what's configured in your [**Sender Authentication Package**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/).

You may have some control over it at the DNS level, but you'll most likely need to talk with someone at SFMC to see what's possible.

Additional Reference:

- [**Maintaining Your Own DNS Records for Your Sending Domain**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/maintaining_your_own_dns_records_for_your_sending_domain/)
- [**Subdomain Delegation Guide**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/subdomain_delegation_guide_for_sender_authentication_package/)